# Sending dynamic variables in sendgrid v3 body using postman

Tags: json, postman, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, postman-pre-request-script

I am trying to send the emails via Sendgrid using v3 API using postman, I have created 3 separate variables in 3 different requests, I want to pass all those 3 variables in a single mail, for that I have used below sendgrid
 `https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send` 
with below body

```
{
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [
        {
          "email": "testing@test.com",
          "name": "API Testing"
        }
      ],
      "subject": "API testing successful"
    }
  ],
  "from": {
    "email": "noreply@testApi.com",
    "name": "API Testing"
  },
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "text/plain",
      "value": "{{variable1}}"  //In variable1 has a dynamic values
    }
  ]
}
```

but the above format sending the mail body as {{Variable1}}, can someone help me on this?

Comment: Can update the question with details about the variables being used and how you're setting this up in Postman. Feels like the question is missing half the details.

Comment: *I want to pass all those 3 variables in a single mail*  This is contradictory statement with the code shown in the question. What are these three variables? do you want to call a same request three times with a different data?

Answer (score 1):

For handlebar {{ variable_value }} substitutions in dynamic HTML templates, u need to pass the variable value as JSON structure with the key as "dynamic_template_data" as part of personalizations.
U also need to pass the (API Key) Authorization  as "Authorization: and Value as "Bearer ".
In the Request Body pass the personalizations object.

```
{
"personalizations": [
    {
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "ron@***",
            }
        ],
        "dynamic_template_data": {
            "<variable_name>": <variable_value>
        }
    }
],
"from": {
    "email": "development@crosspaymt.com",
    "name": "Development Team"
},
"content": [
    {
        "type": "text/html",
        "value": "replace body with template content"
    }
],
"template_id": "******"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of the question you want to send multiple requests with different values.

Say, GET to `https://google.com/q={{search}}` and you have multiple search queries, (dog, chess, marvel, stackoverflow)

- Create a collection in postman
- Add a GET request to `https://google.com/q={{search}}` with necessary headers and hit `Save`
- Create a CSV file with the header `search` and all search values under it
- Hit the run button for the newly created collection
- Set the `Iterations` field to the number of queries you have. In this example it is 4
- Look for the field `Data`, select the created CSV file
- Ensure the data is correctly being picked up by hitting the `Preview` button
- Hit `Run test`
- You can view the output in the `Postman Console`

[image: postman runner]

To open Postman Console `Head to View in the application menu, and click on "Show Postman Console" or use the keyboard shortcut (CMD/CTRL + ALT + C) to open.`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @codeblooded, but that was not what I am looking for, I have found my answer by doing some trial and errors, I have created a variable in Globals in every request like **pm.globals.set("variable1", responseCode.code);** {This is for capturing response code in a variable} in Tests and pass that variable in the required body.